# Open multiple song files from app

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am writing a simple media server application. I'd like the user to be able to build a playlist of songs within my application and then be able to hit "open", which would then open the default media player (the Windows 8 Music App in my case). Currently, I am using Process.Start() to open the app, but that will only open a single song. Does anyone know how to pass a list of songs to the media player (as arguments?) that will act as a play queue? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I haven't used the w8 media player but I'd guess it's not too different from using WMP in w7 which requires you to do something like this; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564122(v=vs.85).aspx however, this isn't going to work if you're starting the process with `Process.Start()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'd really like to be able to do it without adding a media player to my application - I just want to be able to open the default player. The exact functionality I want is when you select multiple .mp3 files in File Explorer and hit "Play" or "Open" - the media player views them as a playlist and plays through all of them.

Comment: I don't think you have to embed the media player in your project. Try instead creating the playlist, importing the playlist, then calling `Process.Start()`.

Comment: What do I set for the process's StartInfo.FileName? If I set it to a music file, it will still only play that single song.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create or modify a SongCollection with the current SDK.

but you can save the songs path in an array and use timer to start next song after last finished

You can use TagLib Sharp to calculate duration time of each song

http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/TagLib%5FSharp

It exposes TagLib.AudioProperties.Duration